# Running a Service without opening the application

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcast

After 3.1 , Android introduced a security feature, where the application's code can't be run unless the user opens the application. Check the link for more info http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/07/13/boot-completed-regression-confirmed.html

I would like to know if anyone has found any hack or work around for this problem, where i can listen to a system broadcasts like boot, connectivity changed and run a service without opening the installed application.

Comment: You can set permissions in your manifest file

Answer (score 0):

This is not what the posts said. You can still register broadcast listeners, or alarms. You just need the user to actually start your application once. And, if the user forcefully stops your application, they'll need to start it manually again.

Why would you want a way around this behavior? It seems to make a lot of sense.

Comment: you did not get my question , i think, my requirement is to run a code of my application, without the user ever opening my application.

Comment: This is not even an answer, please post it as a comment.